# Accessing results from collect() using neo4j-php-client

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, graphaware

**The below displays:**
Marlena has 12 paintings (which is basically from the docs)

How do I access the data in collect(Paintings)
ex: title

```
$query = "MATCH (n:Artist)-[:PAINTED]->(Painting) RETURN n.first_name, collect(Painting) as paintings";
$result = $client->run($query);

foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
    echo sprintf('%s has %d paintings', $record->value('n.first_name'), count($record->value('paintings')));
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

**I would like to display:**

Artist Name:

- painting title
- painting title
- etc

I assume this data can be pull from either Painting or paintings. I am just unsure how to put together the query. It will display using print_r and the record so I know the data is coming through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) I suggest you alias your return values, it is easier to fetch them at the driver level

b) The paintings record value returns an array of `Node` objects, thus is iterable, no need to count for doing the for loop :

```
$query = "MATCH (n:Artist)-[:PAINTED]->(Painting) RETURN n.first_name as firstName, collect(Painting) as paintings";
$result = $client->run($query);

foreach($result->records() as $record) {
    echo sprintf('%s painted %d paintings', $record->get('firstName'), count($record->get('paintings'))) . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($record->get('paintings') as $painting) {
        echo sprintf('%s - %d views', $painting->value('title'), $painting->value('views')) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated and it works as I expected it would. I can't help but think I must have missed something simple during my initial tests. Because that looks a lot like what I tried when I started.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$query = "MATCH (n:Artist)-[:PAINTED]->(Painting) RETURN n.first_name, collect(Painting) as paintings";
$result = $client->run($query);

foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
    echo sprintf('%s has %d paintings:<br/>', $record->value('n.first_name'), count($record->value('paintings')));
    foreach ($record->value('n.paintings') as $painting) {
        echo sprintf('- %s<br/>', $painting->value('title'));
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above does not work and only displays what I had initially.

Jill has 1 paintings:

Disha has 7 paintings:

Marlena has 12 paintings:

Sandy has 4 paintings:

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work with the following:

```
foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
    $fname = $record->values()[0]->get('first_name');
    $lname = $record->values()[0]->get('last_name');
    echo '<strong>'.$fname.' '.$lname.' painted:</strong><br/>';
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($record->values()[1]); $x++) {
            print_r($record->values()[1][$x]->get('title'));
            echo ' - ';
            print_r($record->values()[1][$x]->get('views'));
            echo ' views<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Which provides the following output:

First Name Last Name painted:

- Lumine - 86 views
- Pooled Water - 69 views
- Still Lake - 125 views

**Final Notes**
I actually tried code similar to what you suggested during my struggle to get this working. I'm a bit confused why it does not.

So I'm left wondering. Is what I come up with acceptable?

Comment: The php client offers a couple of helpers for working with result sets, especially read https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client#handling-results-from-v3-to-v4

Comment: Read that 1000 times now. Nothing I've put together seems to do the trick except what I've done above.

Comment: I added an answer with a simplified version